# Using distinct-values within an xpath predicate

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm working with XSLT/Xpath 2.0 and am trying to write an xpath statement that will allow me to filter some duplicate nodesets I have in my XML. Here's an example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
    <card>
        <TimeCard>1234</TimeCard>
        <tax>HST</tax>
        <adjAmt>-112</adjAmt>
    </card>
    <card>
        <TimeCard>1234</TimeCard>
        <tax>GST</tax>
        <adjAmt>-112</adjAmt>
    </card>
    <card>
        <TimeCard>4321</TimeCard>
        <tax>HST</tax>
        <adjAmt>-50</adjAmt>
    </card>
    <card>
        <TimeCard>4321</TimeCard>
        <tax>GST</tax>
        <adjAmt>-50</adjAmt>
    </card>
    <card>
        <TimeCard>2121</TimeCard>
        <tax>GST</tax>
        <adjAmt>-55</adjAmt>
    </card>
</test>
```

I need an xpath that would return "adjAmt" but only once per "TimeCard". My host system creates duplicate "card" entries for "adjAmt" when different types of taxes are charged. In the above example, I only one it to return -112, -50, and -55; one entry per "timecard".

I've tried using distinct-values in a multitude of different spots against the timecard element but have not had any luck.

Anyone have any suggestions on what might work best?

Comment: As you have used the [tag:xslt-2.0] you could use `xsl:for-each-group` to group your `card` elements by the `TimeCard` child value and then select `adjAmt` of each group (first item in a group is the context node inside of `for-each-group` anyway). Not sure why you need an XPath predicate or what the context is but in XSLT you could certainly write a function doing the grouping and selecting those `adjAmt` elements and use the function in a predicate if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2 or 3 you could use `for-each-group group-by` to group the `card` elements by the `TimeCard` child element and then return the context node's `adjAmt` child or its number value as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:group-and-select-first" as="xs:decimal*">
      <xsl:param name="cards" as="element(card)*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$cards" group-by="TimeCard">
          <xsl:sequence select="xs:decimal(adjAmt)"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="mf:group-and-select-first(test/card)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2BP

I have wrapped that grouping code into a function as your question talks about using the code in an XPath predicate, the example simply calls the function in a function call of an `xsl:value-of select` expression but of course you can as well use that function inside of a predicate if needed.

Answer (score 0):

## Using [saxon](/questions/tagged/saxon)

#### `distinct-values()` from [xpath-2.0](/questions/tagged/xpath-2.0)  :

```
$ saxon-lint --xpath '
   for $x in distinct-values(/test/card/TimeCard/text())
      return (/test/card/TimeCard[text()=$x]/following-sibling::adjAmt/text())[1]
' file.xml
```

or

```
$ xidel -se '
   for $x in distinct-values(/test/card/TimeCard/text())
      return (/test/card/TimeCard[text()=$x]/following-sibling::adjAmt/text())[1]
' file.xml
```

#### `group by` from [xquery-3.0](/questions/tagged/xquery-3.0)  :

```
$ saxon-lint --no-pi --xquery '
  for $card in test/card group by $tcard := $card/TimeCard
     return $card[1]/adjAmt/data()
' file.xml
```

or

```
$ xidel -s --xquery '
  for $card in test/card group by $tcard := $card/TimeCard
     return $card[1]/adjAmt/data()
' file.xml
```

Credit to Martin Honnen for this last query

Check [saxon wrapper](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint)
 <sub><sup>my own project</sup></sub>

Comment: XQuery 3 which Saxon supports has a `group by` clause you could use instead of that `distinct-values` based grouping e.g. `for $card in test/card group by $tcard := $card/TimeCard return $card[1]/adjAmt/data()`

Comment: On the other hand I don't see why your suggested XQuery would not work with XPath 2 or 3.

Comment: Not sure whether you got me wrong or simply got that edit wrong but the `group by` suggestion is not supported in XPath, for the `group by` you need XQuery. On the other hand your original `for in return` expression suggested as XQuery would pass as an XPath 2 or 3 solution as well.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Is it OK now ?

Comment: Well, the expression you have used in that example tagged as [tag:xpath-2.0] is indeed an XPath 2.0 expression but the tool command line confusingly uses `saxon-lint --no-pi --xquery`. But I guess that is because the tool calls Saxon from the command line where you can only do XSLT or XQuery but not pure XPath. That way some confusion of the used language remains.

Comment: I can use xpath with --xpath switch

Comment: As far as I could judge from reading the Perl code the `--xpath` argument is feed to `net.sf.saxon.Query` as XQuery. I don't think a command line use of Saxon allows pure XPath evaluation.

Comment: But do you means that Saxon is not a proper lib to do proper xpath or I misunderstood ? Do you know a 'right way' with the 'right switch' of Saxon ?

Comment: Saxon doesn't provide a command line switch to use pure XPath but as XPath is a subset of XQuery it can evaluate XPath expressions as XQuery. To use pure XPath you would need to write Java code using Saxon http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/xpath-api/s9api-xpath.html